# Python lets comparison of values in a list to float32 but not float

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is with python 3.x.
Python allows comparing list of floats with `np.float32` but not with `float`.

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.float32(0.5)
>>> 
>>> l = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
>>> l<a
array([False, False, False, False, False])

>>> b = 0.5
>>> l<b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

Comment: The error message explicitly states that ``<`` is not supported in this case. What makes you think it is not expected behaviour?

Comment: Why is `l` a list instead of a numpy array?  Inequality tests on lists are different, and limited.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison of list to `np.float32` is handled by numpy library via operator overloading methods which returns a `np.array` but comparison to `float` datatype is handled by core python which throws error.